# SaveChanges() generating different queries and not saving some data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 7.0.5.

I have a method that runs in a background job that is supposed to run an import and set the `Status` on the header record for whether the import failed validations, failed the import process, or was successful.

I've got a problem where this process runs, but sometimes does not update the `Status` of the header record.

Every time I run this process it's the same process. I'm trying to import an invalid file that immediately fails validations. This then makes a list of `ImportError` objects that are linked to the header as a collection property. After these `ImportErrors` are added to the header it sets the header `Status` to `Invalid` and sets an `Error` property to a readable error.

Sometimes this works perfectly and the `Status` and `Error` fields are saved along with the `ImportErrors`.

Sometimes this only saves the `ImportErrors` and not the header record.

I've added some logging to write the `Status` to the console as well as the result of the `SaveChanges()` method, which is the number of records that were changed.

In the successful runs I can see the `Status` being set to `Invalid` and there are 7 total changes to the database. Change no. 1 is the header record updating. Changes 2-7 are the `ImportErrors` being saved.

In the unsuccessful runs I still see the `Status` being set to `Invalid`, but there are only 6 changes being saved to the database. And then when I query the database I can see that the `Error` field is empty and the `Status` has not changed at all from the `Processing` state that it starts in.

I ran SQL Server profiler for both a successful and failed run and the generated SQL is different.

- For the successful runs it generates a merge statement and an update statement.
- For the unsuccessful runs it only generates the merge statement with no update.

I can't see any differences between the 2 scenarios and the `Status` is updated to `Invalid` in both cases.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task ImportAsync(int importHeaderId)
{
  var header = this.context.ImportHeaders
                .Include(t => t.ImportErrors)
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.ImportHeaderId == importHeaderId);

  var validationErrors = this.GetValidationErrors();

  if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
  {
    foreach (var error in validationErrors)
    {
      header.ImportErrors.Add(error);
    }

    header.ImportProcess.Error = "Validation failed. Please see import errors for details.";
    header.ImportProcess.Status = Enums.Status.Invalid;
    var noOfChanges = await this.context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    this.logger.LogDebug(noOfChanges.ToString());
    this.logger.LogDebug(header.ImportProcess.Status.ToString());
  } else { ... }
}
```

Here is the generated SQL for a failed run (minus the data):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
MERGE [ImportErrors] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, 0),
(@p3, @p4, @p5, 1),
(@p6, @p7, @p8, 2),
(@p9, @p10, @p11, 3),
(@p12, @p13, @p14, 4),
(@p15, @p16, @p17, 5)) AS i ([CreatedOn], [Message], [ImportHeaderId], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([CreatedOn], [Message], [ImportHeaderId])
VALUES (i.[CreatedOn], i.[Message], i.[ImportHeaderId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ImportErrorId], i._Position;
```

Here is the generated SQL for a successful run (minus the data):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
MERGE [ImportErrors] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, 0),
(@p3, @p4, @p5, 1),
(@p6, @p7, @p8, 2),
(@p9, @p10, @p11, 3),
(@p12, @p13, @p14, 4),
(@p15, @p16, @p17, 5)) AS i ([CreatedOn], [Message], [ImportHeaderId], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([CreatedOn], [Message], [ImportHeaderId])
VALUES (i.[CreatedOn], i.[Message], i.[ImportHeaderId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ImportErrorId], i._Position;
UPDATE [ImportHeaders] SET [Audit_ModifiedOn] = @p18, [ImportProcess_Error] = @p19, [ImportProcess_Status] = @p20
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [ImportHeaderId] = @p21;
```

Comment: You are going to need to show us some code. Perhaps the change tracker is not tracking these objects properly?

Comment: Please add some code, ideally a [mre] (Also the generated SQL can be useful too). Also what what is `Status` and if it is a enum - what is it's default value?

Comment: Status is an enum. The default is Created. This changes to Processing when the validations and import start. It should get changed to Invalid during this process, but stays as Processing.
I'll add some basic code, but it's literally just get thing from context, set fields, then save.

Comment: Post the minimum amount of code that actually reproduces the problem. `SaveChanges` saves *all* the changes to the objects it tracks. It's not a database connection but a Unit of Work. Different data result in different queries. If there are no modified objects there's no reason to generate an `UPDATE` clause

Comment: Check what the queries show. The first one shows an INSERT (`MERGE` is *only* used to ensure the order of the returned IDs) in `ImportErrors`. The second shows an INSERT in `ImportErrors` and an update in  `ImportHeaders` *in the same transaction*. Are you calling `SaveChanges` *twice*? Does one of them persist changes only to `ImportErrors` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, but if I could easily reproduce this issue it would either be the biggest bug in entity framework or it would be so easy to fix that I wouldn't be having this issue. That's all you're getting unless you can ask more specific  questions than just asking for less code

Comment: As for your question of calling `SaveChanges()` twice. It's in the code I put above. I call it once at the start before affecting `ImportErrors`, then once at the end. Sometimes the header saves. Sometimes it doesn't. `ImportErrors` always inserts values into the db

Comment: @TheEvilMetal it may be there but the code is too long, and it's unclear what the *data* is. There are missing code parts too. The first query shows that `Errors` were added but `Headers` weren't modified.

Comment: I'll remove parts of the code, but all you're going to get is code that works perfectly fine everywhere else. That does not help me because there's obviously more going on that ISNT in the code above. The problem isnt with the code above, it's somewhere else. WHERE DO I LOOK

Comment: Try  `this.context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` before each run.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Already tried that. No difference

Comment: Well, it can be 1)  `GetValidationErrors` doing something wrong 2) Multi threading issue.

Comment: GetValidationErrors doesn't even touch the database. This is mostly calculations in memory.

Comment: And wouldn't the fact that it's a service with an injected db context remove the possibility of multithreading issues? Ignoring the fact that I am running this locally with no other users. And there's no threading involved in this process at all

Comment: I don't know how it is injected. Multithreading issues with `async` are possible. If your process is background task, better to allocate and dispose `DbContext` exactly in `ImportAsync` method.

Comment: Since you are not showing the code. Bro. Create a stored procedure and run the code at the database side.

Comment: After finding the actual bug none of these suggestions worked or would've helped. And changing the code presented would've done nothing to help. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you can check to help narrow down the problem, and fixing this issue will depend on how this code is actually being called. You mention "background job", and this is clearly an asynchronous method. I believe the culprit will be related to change tracking within the DbContext. From the comments it sounds like you have tried `ChangeTracker.Clear()`, but since the code example does not outline that, it's unclear if it's been used in the right place. (I.e. it should be the first line of code in the method)

There is also one bug, and this might be related to the issue: you are eager loading ImportErrors, but you are not eager loading ImportProcess:

```
    var header = this.context.ImportHeaders
            .Include(t => t.ImportErrors)
            .Include(t => t.ImportProcess)
            .First(t => t.ImportHeaderId == importHeaderId);
```

This could explain some wonky behaviour because if the injected DbContext happened to be already tracking the ImportProcess for the Header being edited, the reference would be resolved even if not eagerly requested with `Include`. If the instance was not being tracked then it would be lazy loaded if LL is enabled, or you *should* be getting a `NullReferenceException` when you try and access it unless your code is doing something it shouldn't like automatically initializing ProcessHeader.ImportProcess to a `new ImportProcess()` or something of the like.

The first step would be to add an output for the existing header status when you first load the record:

```
public async Task ImportAsync(int importHeaderId)
{
    var header = this.context.ImportHeaders
            .Include(t => t.ImportErrors)
            .Include(t => t.ImportProcess)
            .First(t => t.ImportHeaderId == importHeaderId);
    this.logger.LogDebug($"{importHeaderId}: {header.ImportProcess.Status}");
    // ....
}
```

When you run through your scenario and find that the UPDATE for the header doesn't get changed, what did this import line report? was in "Processing" or already "Invalid"?  Note: I don't recommend using the "OrDefault" methods unless you expect and handle a scenario where no data is returned. It is better to handle the exception with a call stack pointing at this line if a row is not found, than handling a `NullReferenceException` on some future line which might reference 3 or more values that could possibly be #null. (as can often be the case when using "OrDefault" by default)

Without seeing the entire code and how this code is running and being verified, my leading suspicion is that you have a potential race condition where while this code is executing and should be setting the status to "Invalid", some other code on another thread is executing and in some scenarios setting it back to "Processing". For instance, have you been able to reproduce the behaviour locally while debugging and stepping through this code? Or are you relying on the logger output with this background code running in its entirety to see these issues manifest?

If this is intended to be run as a background process, I would highly recommend scoping the DbContext instance to the method rather than using a module level (and likely injected) instance. For instance try the following modifications:

```
public async Task ImportAsync(int importHeaderId)
{
    using (var localContext = new AppDbContext());

    var header = localContext.ImportHeaders
                .Include(t => t.ImportErrors)
                .Include(t => t.ImportProcess)
                .First(t => t.ImportHeaderId == importHeaderId);

    var validationErrors = this.GetValidationErrors();

    if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var error in validationErrors)
        {
          header.ImportErrors.Add(error);
        }

        header.ImportProcess.Error = "Validation failed. Please see import errors for details.";
        header.ImportProcess.Status = Enums.Status.Invalid;
        var noOfChanges = await localContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        this.logger.LogDebug(noOfChanges.ToString());
        this.logger.LogDebug(header.ImportProcess.Status.ToString());
    } 
    else { ... }
}
```

... as a test. To properly implement that with DI, inject a `DbContextFactory` that this method can use to construct an instance of the `DbContext`. (`using (var localContext = this.dbContextFactory.Create());`) This ensures that the DbContext instance for this background method is isolated. This DbContext may need to be sent to GetValidationErrors *if* the Error entities created by this method contain any references to entities loaded by a DbContext in that method. If GetValidationErrors has any code that load entities from `this.context` and associate those to the Error object(s) that get returned, then you will need to pass the "localContext" instance into this method and load those associated entities using that localContext, not `this.context`.

If the above modification appears to work then it would seem you have a bit of a cross-thread race condition in your code. You may still need to do further testing and checking because while this might fix he fact that the UPDATE will go through, modifications on the DI DbContext could still be saved by other code, overwriting the value back to "InProgress" if the change tracker notes a value has been changed. Whenever you have code that can have records updated concurrently, either within a single application with background processes or multiple users, etc. it is advisable to have, and build handling code around row versioning on records. These are either an incrementing counter or a unique timestamp managed by the database that gets incremented/changed whenever a row is updated. EF can work with these and detect when a row version has changed behind the scenes. Something like this may be necessary if there is a possibility of race conditions with data updates.

That should hopefully provide some ideas on things to check.

Comment: ImportProcess is a value object. This basically just adds columns to the existing ImportHeader. It's not necessary to load it separately, it is always loaded with the header.

Comment: I'll be removing some of the code to eliminate those possibly causing trouble, then test some more. The actual code involves downloading a file and then running checks against the file structure. I'll get this to be as small as possible, then start adding some of the checks that you recommend here like the definitely-isolated context. I'll update later once I have more info or a solution

Comment: Also the Status being on the value object wouldn't be the problem. The status being there is a new change, part of unrelated changes. This inconsistent status save problem has been an issue on both the header and the value object.

Comment: Good update so far. Turns out that the framework that we are using to queue background processes has a bug. This sets the Status and queues the background worker at the same time. Meaning that when my method starts the status is unchanged from what it was before. It should go from Invalid to Processing, then back to Invalid. Instead it goes from Invalid, into the worker. Tries to save the Invalid status, but the status is already Invalid so nothing saves. Then the framework finally saves the Status as Processing. From a user perspective this is so quick it looks like it was always Processing.

Comment: +1 and accepted for actually giving advice that helped locate the problem. Instead of just harping on for more code that isn't even the problem